# How to show content in a fancybox?

Tags: fancybox

I'm trying to show a form inside a fancybox but i can't get it to show something.
I dont get how this fancybox works.

My code looks like this:

`<a href="#divForm" id="fancyButton">Show Fancybox</a>
    <div id="divForm" >
    <form action="code_eingabe.php" method="post">
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><h1>E575 - Gewinnspiel</h1></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><?php if(isset($text)){echo $text;} ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="code"/></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit!"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your content with a div that has `display: none`

```
<div id="divForm" style="display: none">
<-- put your content here -->
</div>
```

**EDIT**
to pop up : see this sample of a popped up fancybox content when register :

```
$("#Register").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("This is a fancybox! Register here.")
        $('#CheckoutOptions').fancybox('');
    }
})
```

Comment: but how do i make it pop up?

Comment: See the **EDIT** on my answer

Comment: i now got it to show the content, but how do i now get it to the center and to darken the background when it pops up?

Comment: think about '`modal window`' , Mark this answer as Accepted if it was helpful

Comment: here is all what you need to manage alerts background and position . Being dependent on the web browser used is not a good thing : here's the link : http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/